# IIS 6 weird behavior with Local Path over Windows 2003 Server

Tags: cakephp, iis, web-applications, iis-7, iis-6

I have a site who needs to be pointed to: `inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp\app\webroot\`

If I point the "**Default Web Site**" to that directoy, my web application works perfectly.

Now, as I want to add more sites to that same computer, I am pointing the "**Default Web Site**" to `inetpub\wwwroot\` and the concrete folder for my web application (cakephp) to the previous path `inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp\app\webroot\`.

When I do this I have noticed it doesn't even execute the index.php file located inside `inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp\app\webroot\` contrary as it should. It only does it when accessing directly to the root of the site.

To clarify it:

- `www.myweb.com/cakephp/` executes `inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp\app\webroot\index.php`
- `www.myweb.com/cakephp/actionName/` does **NOT** executes `inetpub\wwwroot\cakephp\app\webroot\index.php`

Why is this happening? Why it doesn't recognize the given path when I add any parameter to the URL? 
It tries to list the folder content instead...

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
http://www.myweb.com/cakephp/index.php/Controllername/
```

For example:

```
http://www.myweb.com/cakephp/index.php/pages/home/
```

if that *is* working, then 'URL rewriting' isn't working.

URL Rewriting doesn't work out-of-the-box on IIS, but can be configured with the instructions in the documentation:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#url-rewrites-on-iis7-windows-hosts

However, your setup may need to be slightly different than the documentation because you've installed your website in a subdirectory

Comment: CakePHP documentation only talks about IIS 7, and IIS 6 doesn't work with `web.config` files. Therefor, the only way to do it is using Helicon ISAPI_rewrite3 to modify the `http.conf` file and create the rewrite rules. It was not so simple as the `htaccess` file detailed [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/jamesmking/2008/04/12/cakephp-on-iis6-with-fastcgi-sql-server-2005-and-isapi_rewrite) but I finally did it as I detail [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/476525/how-to-rewrite-rules-for-two-subfolders-using-mod-rewrite/476625#476625)

Comment: Glad you got it working, I haven't worked with IIS since my ASP days (Windows NT), so happy to hear you figured it out